# Root FS goes into ReadOnly Mode in 2 days after clean Reboot

Tags: linux, fsck, suse, hp

I have a Suse OS machine. The root FS goes into RO mode by itself. After a clean reboot it is back in RW mode but does not stay there. After 2 days it goes back to RO mode. I performed FSCK on individual FileSystem and was clean. Reports no errors. When The system is in RO Mode, I tried to fdisk -l and it does not give me any disk details. So I thought it may be hardware issues and provided AHS logs to HP. But they came back saying they did not find any Hardware issues. 
Could anybody please suggest what further actions I can take ?

Comment: Can you please provide more details about the distro, your partition setup, filesystem type. Usually, there's something in the logs at the time a filesystem goes into read-only, could you paste it here? Make sure to remove sensitive data from that output.

Comment: Typically these days `/etc/fstab` says that `/` is to be remounted RO on errors, so I would suspect hardware as well. Next time it happens I suggest running `dmesg` to see if the kernel messages give you any clue. Installing S.M.A.R.T tools whilst the system is in RW mode may be worthwhile.

Comment: Here are some of the log details I could find. 

[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] DMI: HP ProLiant DL120 Gen9/ProLiant DL120 Gen9, BIOS P86 01/22/2018
[    0.000000]   C0000-DFFFF write-protect
[    0.000000]   F0000-FFFFF write-protect

Comment: 1(xxxx)(/a/b/R/c):~ -> sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ed6c4
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1060863      529408   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1060864     9461759     4200448   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         9461760   976773119   483655680   8e  Linux LVM

Comment: sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               sys-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                6
  Open LV               6
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               461.25 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              118079

Comment: Much better to edit the log information into the question than to add it as comments, Easier to read and less likely to be removed.